# ReactJS - The result of my Dice Roll won't display?

Tags: reactjs

First time posting here. I'm trying to display the result of a "Dice Roll" inside a component. As I understand it when you want to display Javascript inside HTML you wrap it in {}. It worked for something literal like 2+2. Or standalone variables like let x = 2+2. But trying to pull a piece out of a function to plug it in seems like an issue? I started learning all of this last week so sorry you have to spoonfeed this.

I've tried turning the number outputted into a string and returning that. (That's still in the code.)
I've tried running this component as a function instead of a class.
I've tried using an inline function for onClick.
I've tried moving the function under and inside the return.
I've tried keeping the function inside it's own component and importing the result to this Dice Component then having that route to the app.js
I've tried to use states but tbh I'm not sure how that was supposed to work, only ever used them for Array of Objects. Plan on learning that later on.
I've returning 'test' and 'D20RollValue' inside the function.
I've tried NOT using this.
And I've looked up other tutorials and examples of how something like this is supposed to work.

```
import React from "react"

class Dice extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // Dice Rolling
    function D20Click() {
      let D20RollValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)
      const test = "Rolled " + D20RollValue
      console.log(test)
    }
    return (
      <div className="D20Container">
        <button className="RollD20Button" onClick={D20Click}>
          Roll D20
        </button>
        <p>Insert Result Here: {this.D20RollValue}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dice
```

It works in console.log and when using type of for test and D20RollValue they both display string and number respectively so that works. But this.D20RollValue and this.test don't display anything at all. It's like they are being skipped and no error is popping up in the console about it.

*Hope I'm formatting this post right.*

Comment: Hi Galen and Welcome you, I can't see a function called `D20RollValue` in your component. also, if it's there, to be actually able to get a value from it, you will need to invoke it such like `<p>{this.D20RollValue()}</p>` instead of having no `()` at the end of the expression.

Comment: Oh sorry let me edit that. The function is D20Click.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `D20RollValue` to component's state and then set it on click:

```
import React from "react"

class Dice extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {D20RollValue: 0}
  }

   // Dice Rolling
    D20Click = () => {
      let D20RollValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)
      const test = "Rolled " + D20RollValue
      console.log(test)
      this.setState({D20RollValue: D20RollValue});
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="D20Container">
        <button className="RollD20Button" onClick={this.D20Click}>
          Roll D20
        </button>
        <p>Insert Result Here: {this.state.D20RollValue}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dice
```

EDIT: You also need to move out your dice rolling function from render.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was fine until I pressed the button and got TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. Any other ideas?

Comment: Good catch @AsafAviv, changed it to arrow method.

Comment: That's it! Thanks a ton! Had a feeling it would be a state thing since I didn't learn that yet lol.

Answer (score 0):

your problem was D20RollValue is a local variable in the function you couldn't use it outside. also here another solution could help you.

```js
import React from "react";

class Dice extends React.Component {
  state = {
    D20RollValue: 0
  };

  diceRolling = () => {
    this.setState({
      D20RollValue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="D20Container">
        <button className="RollD20Button" onClick={this.diceRolling}>
          Roll D20
        </button>
        <p>Insert Result Here: {this.state.D20RollValue}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dice;
```